# Magento 2 - how to change "Please specify a payment method." message on checkout page?

Tags: magento2, checkout

I want to update
 **"Please specify a payment method."** with background color on checkout page.I have updated text in module-sales/i18n/en_US.csv file but this is not working for me.

Please help me.

Comment: WHich Magento version, you have suing  2.1  or 2.2. If using 2.1 then the translation is not working.

Comment: Hi @AmitBera,I am using 2.2.

Comment: Have you did static content deploy properly?

Answer (score 1):

please check in your csv file

**"Please specify a payment method"** there is no white space and trimmed your text

please clear cache and check

Comment: please clear cache and cookie of browser to check

Comment: Hello @Rutvee ,I want to change for payment method not shipping method.

Comment: ohh sorry @akgola i miss understood

Answer (score 0):

You can update text in direct in file where it comes from.

```
PackageName\vendor\magento\module-multishipping\Model\Checkout\Type\Multishipping.php at line no 717.

...........................
...........................

protected function _validate()
{
    $quote = $this->getQuote();

    /** @var $paymentMethod \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod */
    $paymentMethod = $quote->getPayment()->getMethodInstance();
    if (!$paymentMethod->isAvailable($quote)) {
        throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
            __('Please specify a payment method.') //here you can change text
        );
    }
    ...............

    return $this;
}
```

**Try this and let me know if you are still facing the same issue**